# Finding a gene of similar length

Tags: gene, ensembl

I would like to find a few genes that are similar in length to a gene of interest, and by that I mean the total length of a canonical transcript including introns. This is proving to be surprisingly hard using web based lookups.

The gene of interest is 14.5Kb long and I wanted a table of genes and their canonical lengths to compare and contrast to in order to pick a few to have a look at in some vcfs I have.

I have a low bioinformatics ability but happy to give things a go!

All the best

I have tried:

- first download a file of all gene files from ensembl which looks like this:
  [image]

Then in R:

```
x <- read.delim("all_genes_bed.txt")
x$length <- (x$Gene.end..bp.-x$Gene.start..bp.)
x <- subset(x, x$length >14000 & x$length <15000)
```

Then I just had a look in the RStudio browser.

That seemed to work!

Comment: I would simply download a GTF annotation files, filter for `type=gene`, subtract end from start coordinate to get the length, and from this make a simple lookup table, listing gene name and length. This you can sort by length and then check genes that intersect the length of your gene. Do you need code suggestions?

Comment: @ATpoint many thanks for taking the time to answer. Would I get this from ensembl? I think once I have the file I could do that in R. Not sure how to get the whole gene table though

Comment: @tactolimus Yes, you could get it from Ensembl. How about trying something, see how far you get and if you hit the wall then just edit it to the toplevel post and we can have a look to debug it.

Comment: @ATpoint I think I solved it, let me know if this seems reasonble

Comment: Yes, I think this is reasonable.